# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information](http://se.awio.com/election.html).

The information presented is:

What the candidate wrote when nominating themselves.

- Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
- Up-vote/down-vote ratio
- Average reputation earned per post
- Average reputation earned per day.
- Participation in other Stack Exchange sites.

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)

Comment: Great work, thanks!

Comment: @Raphael - don't thank me, thank Yi Jiang.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify. Above comment has to be read as: "Yi Jiang, great work, thank you for putting this together! ChrisF, thank you for mentioning it here, I would not have known it existed otherwise." ;)